# gcc function attributes - how to use them?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, gcc, sse

I would need to mark one function in a big file as SSE4.1 enabled and leave all the rest non-SSE4.1... so I'm wondering why

```
int sse3_func (void) __attribute__ ((__target__ ("sse3")));
```

if I declare a function to be compiled with sse3, and I'm compiling the entire application on a system where there's no sse3 support... how am I supposed to be able to include the sse3 headers???

I would get a "#error SSE4.1 instruction set not enabled" when including them. Is this the intended way to use it? I can understand disabling sse and other ISAs, but to add them... it's rather stupid, isn't it?

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: Try a snapshot of gcc-4.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to decouple these functions from the rest of the unit. Some refactoring was needed.